# Gaussian curvature of an Isothermic parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry

ive done some research on the site, but i have not found a proper answer (yet).
So, i have to prove the following:

Consider an isothermic parametr. with the metric given by
$ g_{ij} = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda^2 & 0\\
0 & \lambda^2 
\end{pmatrix}$ where $ \lambda = \lambda(u^1,u^2) >0 $
Show that:
$K=\frac{\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2}{\lambda^4} -\frac{\lambda_{11}+\lambda_{22}}{\lambda^3}$

Ive tried to use Brioschi`s formula, and ive tried to use the alternative one for orthogonal parametrizations.

If anyone could outline the calculations, it would help quite alot
thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, after ~6 hours of staring at this thing i finally got the answer. Take Brioschis formula, and take into account the fact that 
$\frac{d}{du} \lambda^2(u,v) = \frac{d}{du} ( \lambda(u,v) \lambda(u,v)) = 2* \lambda (u,v) \lambda_u (u,v)$
Correctly feeding the formula with this, it will give the correct result

Comment: This "fact" is simply "applying the chain rule". Nothing Special about this at all.